# A vb.net set of code does not resort the original text file, it only displays the highest alphabetical name 9 x

Tags: vb.net, console

The code was taken from a YouTube video that I watched at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyN6pZmd2Pk.

There are no errors in the code, just a list of the name Aiden, which was in the original text file 9 places down.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Imports System.IO

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myArray As New List(Of String)
    Using myReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(".\myFile.txt")
        'telling VB that we're using a StreamREader, read a line at a time
        Dim myLine As String
        myLine = myReader.ReadLine 'assigns the line to String Variable myLine
        Do While (Not myLine Is Nothing)
            myArray.Add(myLine) 'adding it to the list of words in the array
            Console.WriteLine(myLine)
            myLine = myReader.ReadLine
        Loop
    End Using
    SortMyArray(myArray)
    'Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Sub SortMyArray(ByVal mySort As List(Of String))
    Dim Tmp As String, writePath As String = ".\sorted.txt"
    Dim max As Integer = mySort.Count - 1
    Dim myWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(writePath)

    For Loop1 = 0 To max - 1
        For Loop2 = Loop1 + 1 To max
            If mySort(Loop1) > mySort(Loop2) Then
                Tmp = mySort(Loop2)
                mySort(Loop1) = mySort(Loop1)
                mySort(Loop1) = Tmp

            End If
        Next
        myWriter.WriteLine(mySort.Item(Loop1).ToString())
    Next
    myWriter.Dispose()
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: `mySort(Loop1) = mySort(Loop1)` You should look at this line to fix your typo

Comment: Thanks for that and thanks for getting me to work out my own problem. Part of me always wants to be told, but I know that if I figure it out, it's more powerful :)